# How to properly crop a math operator? A command for the direct factor symbol?

Tags: math-operators, crop, croptrim

I am sorry if this has already been answered, but neither chatgpt provided me with a satisfying answer nor have I found what I am looking for on the stack exchange.
**I would like to know if there is a "canonical" way to crop a math operator in order to create a new one**

Let me be more specific and show you which (apparently missing) operator I would like:
I want to have a **direct factor symbol**, which is a halved direct sum symbol (`\oplus`). I want to keep the left half and get rid of the right half.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

---

Here is what chatgpt provided:
`\newcommand{\eplus}{\mathbin{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0.5\width 0pt}{$\oplus$}}}`

Which is already cool but has alignments problems plus an error occurring:
`missing number, treated as zero`

Thanks in advance for you help!

PS: If you know a package that deals with this symbol this would also satisfy me :)!

---

Here is the (almost full document): (sorry in advance I had to get back to my cls documents, I hope it is in order):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}


\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\@arabic\c@section}

\setitemize[1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setitemize[2]{label=-}
\setenumerate[0]{label=$(\roman*)$}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{esint} 
\usepackage{mathdots}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

% A lot of things (essentially macros and environments + drawings things)

\usepackage{geometry}

\pagestyle{headings}
\\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{sanslabel}{#3}%


\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\eplus}{\mathbin{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0.5\width 0pt}{$\oplus$}}}

\begin{document}

%blabla

\( A \eplus B\)

%blabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok it might take some time, but I'll give the full setup

Comment: We don't need the full setup, we need a small, but compilable test document.

Comment: Yes I tried to reduce it but left the used packages :)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705543/how-to-properly-crop-a-math-operator-a-command-for-the-direct-factor-symbol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off: ChatGPT *seems* to provide sensible answers. Usually, however, they aren't.

However, `\clipbox` is certainly a something to start with.

You shouldn't clip at half width, because you lose most of the vertical bar; next, you want some sidebearing on the right.

The factor 0.484 has been computed “by sight”, with some attempts, and obviously depends on the math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\eplus}{}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\eplus@\relax\mspace{1mu}}}

\newcommand{\eplus@}[2]{%
  \clipbox{0 0 {0.484\width} 0}{$\m@th#1\oplus$}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\eplus B$

$x_{A\eplus B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the braces around `0.484\width`, otherwise you get an error.

Comment: Wow thank you very much, I also tried to adjust the parameter but not as precisely as you did :)